# Restler adds newline to output

Tags: restler

Why I do something like a POST to a restler method, the output seems to always start with a newline character.  How do I prevent that newline character from being put into the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never noticed that behaviour. Could it be some of your files having a bare new line outside of the PHP tags?

Sample API request I've just made in a [test project of mine](http://calories.dev/api/explorer/#!/user/retrieve):

[image]

Comment: One of the files had two blank lines after the ?> tag instead of just one.  Why would that cause extra output to be displayed though?

Comment: I find that if I remove ALL of the closing tags from my files, then I can have as many blank lines as I want and it doesn't echo blank lines.  Very strange.

Comment: That's actually a suggested code style by the PSR :)